# transpose array using malloc

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I think I my code was right but I still can not transpose my array
do I code right for the variable of `malloc` transpose?

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));
int *transpose = (int *)malloc(c * r * sizeof(int));
```

this is my input:

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        cout << "Element at x[" << i << "][" << j << "] : ";
        cin >> *(arr + i * c + j);
    }
}
```

does the transpose code right?

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        *(transpose + j + i * c) = *(arr + i * c + j);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

and the print code was it right?

```
cout << endl << "transpose : " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < r; j++) {
        cout << *(transpose + i * c + j ) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid malloc in C++.

Comment: Why not use `[]` operators like `arr[i*c + j]` instead of `*(arr + i*c + j)`?

Comment: I suggest wrapping these raw pointers in a small class that knows the matrix shape and does the correct computation for you.

Answer (score 3):

Both the transpose and print are wrong.

`+ j + i*c` and `+ i*c + j` are equivalent in adding integers to pointers, just the order is swapped.

It seems the original array has `r` rows and `c` columns, so the transposed array will have `c` rows and `r` columns.

One column of transposed array will have `r` elements, so `r`, not `c`, should be multiplied to the row index of transposed array.

Therefore, transpose should be

```
for(i=0; i<r; i++){
    for(j=0; j<c; j++){
        *(transpose + j*r + i)=*(arr + i*c + j);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

and printing should be

```
cout<<endl<<"transpose : "<<endl;
for(i=0; i<c; i++){
    for(j=0; j<r; j++){
        cout<<*(transpose + i*r + j )<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```